# Click event for a notification in python with Plyer

Tags: python, notifications

```
while(True):
    plyer.notification.notify(
        title = title,
        message = message,
        app_icon = icon,
        timeout = 50
    )
    time.sleep(3600)
```

I want to be able to access a link when the notification is clicked. I have not found anything like a click event in the source code. I was thinking that maybe it could be called when the timeout is 0 or something similar. If there is another way of doing it without plyer it could also work for me, but I have not found anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plyer doesn't support click event on notification. It's sad since this lib is so simple to use, and cross-platform. Would be easy to just add a new parameter. https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plyer.facades.Notification

Answer (score 0):

Try win10toast-click. It is not in-built so you have to pip install it.
You can use

`from win10toast_click import ToastNotifier`

to import it
You can use it by typing

`toaster = ToastNotifier() toaster.show_toast(title=,message=,icon_path=,duration=,threaded=True,callback_on_click=yourfunction )`

after that you could use webbrowser module to create your function to open the link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30771470)